# STM32 DAC triangle generator flat bottom

Tags: stm32, dac

I'm trying to create a triangle signal with DAC via DMA (STM32F407VG DISC1 board). My template array is fine, I've checked it with a plot. But I have some strange flat area on the bottom I've stuck on. I've tried to pull it up to avoid touch of the bottom but it doesn't work. What could be wrong? Here is all related parts of my code:

```
// DAC VAWE BLOCK
uint32_t signal_val[SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
uint32_t signal_ampl=1240; // 2v
uint32_t signal_freq=450;
uint32_t signal_type = 1; // triangle

void calcsin ()
{
    for (int i=0; i<SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        signal_val[i] = ((sin(i*2*PI/SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE) + 1)*signal_ampl) +5;
    }
}
void calctriangle()
{
    for (int i=0; i<(float)SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE/2; i++)
    {
        signal_val[i] = (i/((float)SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE/2.0f))*signal_ampl*2 +5;
    }
    int j=(float)SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE/2;
    for (int i=(float)SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE/2; i<SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        float b = (j/((float)SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE/2.0f))*signal_ampl*2;
        signal_val[i] = (uint32_t)(b) +5; //+5 anywhere to up wave just a little and prevent it's corruption on bottom
        --j;
    }
}

  if (signal_type==1)
      calctriangle();
  else
      calcsin();

 HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC1_CHANNEL_1, signal_val, SIGNAL_TEMPLATE_SIZE, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
```

[image: Triangle]

[image: Sine]

Comment: So what are the values? Do they go down to 0? Is your target range 0..2V so 0..1240? Is the DAC buffer enabled or disabled?

Comment: Please [edit] to add captions below each of your scope photos. Explain what each trace is. The blue looks like a disconnected probe.

Comment: Where you can it is better to use the scope's screen capture capability rather than a photo of the scope.

Comment: DISC1 board use an op-amp to buffer the DAC output? I'd suspect poor operation near 0v.

Comment: Values from buffer go down to 5. DAC output buffer is enabled. 1240 is probably just an artifact due debug, it was near 2v before. The blue line doesn't matter, it's just a reaction of my target system to yellow input. The problem is the yellow line. These photos are the only evidence I have right now, I will try to recreate this situation with pc-based scope. I've tried to make an offset=5 from zero. Is it not enough?

Comment: @arcticP -- personally I think scope photos are perfectly fine, *but only if you can see the whole screen*, i.e. all the scale and trigger info that is displayed. Referring to first image. For future reference. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet of the MCU says that when the DAC buffer is enabled, minimum output voltage is 0.2V.

As you are using 3.3V supply and reference, it corresponds to 12-bit DAC value of 248.